# Uninstall Microsoft DirectAccess from laptop

Tags: vpn

How do I uninstall Microsoft DirectAccess, the built-in VPN software installed in some versions of Windows 7?

**Background**

My IT Operations group attempted installing Microsoft DirectAccess on a small number of laptops. They found that it caused more problems than it solved, so they returned to the Cisco VPN, and they are no longer including it in new laptop images. I was in a test group, and I could like to remove it.

I'm running the 64-bit version of Windows 7 Enterprise SP1. The main issue is that when I receive the internal IPv6 address when I attempt to access domains that have internal and public DNS, like www.OurIntranetSite.example.com.

**Microsoft DirectAccess Documentation**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/dd420463.aspx

Comment: It would be better you contact your IT Department for this rather than trying stuff suggested by internet

Answer (score 0):

As I read at Microsoft's Technet you have to get the file 'DirectAccess_Connectivity_Assistant.msi' and run it on your PC for the uninstall process.

Please go to [this site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274289.aspx) and search for 'uninstall' for further information.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stop it working is to disable the NRPT table entries that direct the client to resolve names to the IPv6 addresses you are seeing.  You can also delete the IPsec tunnel definitions that are used to communicate with the DA server over the IPv6 transition protocol that ended up working.

To delete the NRPT entries open Local Computer Policy (GPEDIT.MSC) and under Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Name Resolution Policy and delete the entries in the table.

To remove the tunnels open "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" and remove the entries under "Connection Security Rules"